# Enthought Canopy can't resolve python-openid

Tags: enthought

I've been trying to install Paste 1.7.5.1-1 from Enthought Canopy's Package Manager, however I get an error: it looks like Canopy can't resolve python-openid:

[image]

Thinking that python-openid was missing completely from my system (it is not listed in the "Available Packages' list in Canopy either), I followed [these directions](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-external-packages-into-Canopy-Python) and installed python-openid using pip. However, the package seems to be there already and further attempts to install Paste keep failing.

[image]

Some help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Enthought Support here) The `Paste` package is not part of the official Canopy repo, but rather the unsupported "Community", and so some dependency issues may arise when installing from these packages. Using the following steps, I was able to get the `Paste` package installed and even ran a few tests:

- From the Canopy Command Prompt, run `pip install python_openid` (note there is no -U and the module uses an underscore, not a dash as in your screenshot from StackOverflow).
- After it installs, use the command line utility enpkg to force an install of paste without resolving dependencies. From the Canopy Command Prompt: `enpkg --no-deps Paste`

Then you can test it out...

Within IPython (either from the command line or Canopy Python pane), try this simple program [found in their docs](http://pythonpaste.org/do-it-yourself-framework.html#writing-a-wsgi-application):

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    return ['Hello world!']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from paste import httpserver
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I was able to install the Paste package following your steps. I was also able to run the scripts with no errors. However, the Canopy package manager still gives me the same errors when I try to install other packages that depend on Paste. In other words, things run but the package manager seems confused.

Comment: You are correct, the Package Manager is confused. It uses it's own package installation utilities (enstaller/enpkg) to track versions and dependencies. By using `pip`, you've stepped outside of its domain. We advise that when using `pip` to install a package, you first need to uninstall the package if previously installed by `enpkg` or the Package Manager. The same goes for working in the other direction, uninstall if previously done through `pip` if attempting with Package Manager. Just remember these are two mechanisms to achieve the same goal, but need to managed carefully.